# Google App Engine Nodejs Error 409

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I'm using a Node Express app with App Engine. Everything's been deploying fine, but I must have had an interrupted deployment because now when I try to deploy using this:

```
gcloud preview app deploy .
```

I get this:

```
Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user <username> is already in progress for app:
s~<appId>, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg 
rollback".
--- end server output ---
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
```

I can't find an appcfg file to rollback, nor any documentation about this issue for a node app.

Answer (score 4):

You can use gcloud preview app deploy . --force
which will implicitly do a rollback (to clear the deploy lock) before attempting the deployment.

Comment: This worked great! You are a machine. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the appcfg.py rollback  command.
Here, create a file as app.yaml and a directory WEB-INF in which there will be two files named as web.xml and appengine-web.xml.